# Assigning Pointer to singleton to object field

Tags: c++, qt, singleton

I have a singleton (named Context) with ofcourse a getInstance method which returns the static pointer to the single instance.

When using this instance in other classes I've been using the Context::getInstance() function. But since I've been calling the method tens of times in the same controller class I was looking for a more straightforward solution.

Can I make an extra field in my Controller class of type Context* and assign the singleton to it in the constructor of my controller by calling Context::getInstance() once? Or will the pointer itself change during the program lifetime?

Comment: If getInstance() never returns NULL then why not return a reference.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a singleton it *should* stay the same object for the lifetime of the program, and so this should be safe.  If you yourself wrote the class, then you should easily be able to check that this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

it won't if you don't change it

another solution could be:

Context* context()
{ return Context::getInstance(); }

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but your solution is not safe - you can access this extra field before the first call of the `getInstance` method by mistake. You should better store a pointer returned by `getInstance` in your "Controller" class somewhere.

Comment: ZuulViewController::ZuulViewController(QObject *parent): QObject(parent), theContext(Context::getInstance())
{
}

This should be safe then ? Since it is impossible to create a Context object without calling getInstance?